# 'Trigger' click on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate a click on the mobile menu toggle on scroll. The code I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on("scroll", clickMenu);

    function clickMenu() {
        var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (wScroll > 1) {
            $(".mobile_nav").trigger("click");
            $(window).off("scroll", clickMenu);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is not working sadly

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (scripts.min.js?ver=4.17.4:2:265844)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:43064)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:41048)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3:5813)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3:11480)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:2880)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:847)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3:11456)
    at clickMenu ((index):15:26)
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3:6404)
```

What  should I do so the click is simulated?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post code where that `slice` part is? Also I see you deleted some code since `if` is opened but never closed.

Comment: And you did it again with comment this time...

Comment: Edited the opening post

Comment: The error is in `scripts.min.js`, ... so we cannot know what is happening there. Probably some click handler code for that `.mobile_nav` element that runs into an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not the problem, probably the problem is in the code where you are calling the method.
Please refer to a working example of your code:

```js
 $(window).on("scroll", clickMenu);

    function clickMenu() {
        var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (wScroll > 1) {
        $(".mobile_nav").trigger("click");
        $(window).off("scroll", clickMenu);
    }}

$(".mobile_nav").on("click", alert('clicked'))
```

```css
body{
  height:120vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mobile_nav"></button>
```

```
<button class="mobile_nav"></button>


$(window).on("scroll", clickMenu);

function clickMenu() {
    var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wScroll > 1) {
        $(".mobile_nav").trigger("click");
        $(window).off("scroll", clickMenu);
    }
}
```

```
$(".mobile_nav").on("click", alert('clicked'))
```

Comment: The site is built with Divi - https://semita.pl/ - could someone please try to diagnose?

Comment: issue is with the action triggered after on mobile_nav click, debug that part